# namespace not found in xaml, but can be used in C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I have a WPF Project **Home**,it will reference a library project which defines namespace 'LibraryProjectExample', I want to use it in the **Home** Project,the namespace can not be found:

```
xmlns:view="clr-namespace:LibraryProjectExample"
```

But when I use `using namespace LibraryProjectExample` in C# code,I can use it normally.

I have checked that the LibraryProject has been referenced by the Home Project, I don't know why i can't use the namespace in xaml.Anyone can tell me,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not adding the assembly to your xaml reference. Look in your LibraryProjectExample project and find it's package name, then you can append it to your namespace declarationlike so 
`xmlns:view="clr-namespace:LibraryProjectExample;assembly=YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use as below in you `Xaml` page.

`xmlns:object="clr-namespace:**namespace**;assembly=*assembly*"`

here `namespace` is your `packagename.classname` and assembly is your `packagename`

For Example, `xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"`

Thank You.

Comment: Sorry,I'm still confused, you mean the "namespace is packagename.classname", is not namespace defined in my library project?In my example mentioned in the question, How should I do?thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Besides* the namespace you should *also* specify the name of the library project/assembly where the namespace is defined:

```
xmlns:view="clr-namespace:LibraryProjectExample;assembly=LibraryProject"
```

You need to change "LibraryProject" in the above sample markup to the actual name of the referenced project where the "LibraryProjectExample" namespace is defined.